# For which values of $p,q$, does the following double integral converge?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

**Question:** For which real numbers $p,q$, does the integral:

$$I=\iint_{|x|+|y|\ge1}\frac{1}{|x|^p+|y|^q}dxdy $$

converge?

**What I tried so far:**

The integrated function, $f(x,y)$, is non-negative.

Based on symmetry arguements, we can look at the integral on the first quadrant of the plane: that is,

$$I'=\iint_{x+y\ge1}\frac{1}{x^p+y^q}dxdy,$$
And then multiply the result by 4 (if it converges).

The domain of integration can be written as a disjoint union (besides a negligible set):

$$E=\underset{E_1}{\{ 0\le x\le 0.5,y\ge 1-x \ge 0.5 \}} \cup \underset{E_2}{\{ 0\le y\le 0.5,x\ge 1-y \ge 0.5 \}}   \cup \underset{E_3}{\{ x,y\ge0.5\} } $$

We need $\iint f$ to converge in all three subsets.

If $q>1$, then $\iint_{E_1}f<\infty$, and if $p>1$ then $\iint_{E_2}f<\infty$.

---

From this point on I'm stuck- I can't figure out the convergence for $E_3$, and I also haven't considered the cases $p\le0$ or $q\le0$ yet (only for $p,q>0$).

How does one approach the rest of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

We can show that

$$I'=\iint_{x+y\ge1}\frac{1}{x^p+y^q}dxdy\ge \int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x^p+1}dx
$$

which diverges for $p\le 1$ and

$$I'=\iint_{x+y\ge1}\frac{1}{x^p+y^q}dxdy\le \int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x^p}dx+\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{y^q}dy+\iint_{x+y\ge1, \, x\le1, \, y\le1}\frac{1}{x^p+y^q}dxdy+\\+\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}\, d\theta\int_1^\infty \frac{r}{r^p\cos^p\theta+r^q \sin^q \theta}dr$$

and the first two integrals converges for $p,q>1$, the third is a proper integral and for the latter assuming wlog $p<q$

$$\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}\, d\theta\int_1^\infty \frac{r}{r^p\cos^p\theta+r^q \sin^q \theta}dr\le\frac \pi 2 \cdot M(p,q)\int_1^\infty \frac1{r^{p-1}}dr$$

where $M(p,q)$ is an upper bound for the function

$$\frac{1}{\cos^p\theta+r^{q-p} \sin^q \theta}$$